# Stored Procedure not returning Value - C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteFromSchoolMain]
    @TblName VARCHAR(50),
    @MainID VARCHAR(10),
    @TblCol VARCHAR(50),
    @rowsCount INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @RelTbl AS Nvarchar(50)
    DECLARE @ColForFK AS Nvarchar(50)
    DECLARE @TblMaterial AS NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @ColMaterialID AS NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @ColMaterialFK AS NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @cmdForMaterial AS NVARCHAR(max)
    DECLARE @TblSubject AS NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @ColSubjectID AS NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @ColSubjectFK AS NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @cmdForSubject AS NVARCHAR(max)

    Set @ColForFK = SUBSTRING(@TblCol,1, DATALENGTH(@TblCol)-2)
    Set @ColForFK = @ColForFK+'FK'

    DECLARE @cmd AS NVARCHAR(max)
    DECLARE @TempCount int

    SET @MainID = ''''+@MainID+ ''''

    SET @RelTbl = 'ClassSubMatRelation'
    --For Class Material
    SET @TblMaterial = 'ClassMaterial'
    SET @ColMaterialID = 'ClassMaterialID'
    SET @ColMaterialFK = 'ClassMaterialFK'

    SET @cmd = N'UPDATE ' + @RelTbl + ' SET Status_Info = 0 WHERE ' +  @ColForFK + ' = ' + @MainID -- Delete from ClassRelation Table
    EXEC(@cmd)
    SET @TempCount = @@ROWCOUNT
    SET @rowsCount = @TempCount + @rowsCount;

    SET @cmd = N'UPDATE ' + @TblName + ' SET Status_Info = 0 WHERE ' +  @TblCol + ' = ' + @MainID -- Delete from Main Table
    EXEC(@cmd)
    SET @TempCount = @@ROWCOUNT 
    SET @rowsCount = @TempCount + @rowsCount;

    -------------------------------------Board-----------------------------------
    IF (@TblName = 'Board')
    BEGIN

        SET @cmdForMaterial = N'UPDATE '+@TblMaterial+' Set Status_Info = 0 where '+@ColMaterialID+' in ( Select s.'+@ColMaterialFK+' from  '+@RelTbl+' s where s.' +  @ColForFK + ' = ' +  @MainID + ' AND s.ClassSubjectFK IN ( SELECT T.ClassSubjectFK FROM ' + @RelTbl + ' T WHERE  T.'+@ColForFK+' = '+ @MainID + ') and s.ClassSubjectFK NOT IN ( SELECT E.ClassSubjectFK FROM ' +@RelTbl+' E WHERE E.'+@ColForFK+' != '+ @MainID +') and s.'+@ColMaterialFK+'  is not null )'
        EXEC(@cmdForMaterial)   
        SET @TempCount = @@ROWCOUNT 
        SET @rowsCount = @TempCount + @rowsCount;
        SET @TempCount = 0;


        --For Class Subject
        SET @TblMaterial = 'ClassSubject'
        SET @ColMaterialID = 'ClassSubjectID'
        SET @ColMaterialFK = 'ClassSubjectFK'

        SET @cmdForMaterial = N'UPDATE '+@TblMaterial+' Set Status_Info = 0 where '+@ColMaterialID+' in ( Select s.'+@ColMaterialFK+' from  '+@RelTbl+' s where s.' +  @ColForFK + ' = ' +  @MainID + ' AND s.ClassSubjectFK IN ( SELECT T.ClassSubjectFK FROM ' + @RelTbl + ' T WHERE  T.'+@ColForFK+' = '+ @MainID + ') and s.ClassSubjectFK NOT IN ( SELECT E.ClassSubjectFK FROM ' +@RelTbl+' E WHERE E.'+@ColForFK+' != '+ @MainID +') and s.'+@ColMaterialFK+'  is not null )'
        EXEC(@cmdForMaterial)   
        SET @TempCount = @@ROWCOUNT 
        SET @rowsCount = @TempCount + @rowsCount;
        SET @TempCount = 0;


    END

        ------------------------------ Class Subject ------------------------------------
    ELSE IF (@TblName = 'ClassSubject')
    BEGIN                   

        SET @cmdForMaterial = N'UPDATE '+@TblMaterial+' Set '+@TblMaterial+'.Status_Info = 0 from '+@TblMaterial+' tm join '+@RelTbl+' rt on rt.'+@ColMaterialFK+' = tm.'+@ColMaterialID+' where rt.'+@ColForFK+ ' = '+ @MainID
        EXEC(@cmdForMaterial)

        SET @TempCount = @@ROWCOUNT 
        SET @rowsCount = @TempCount + @rowsCount;
        SET @TempCount = 0;
    END

END
GO
```

And I'm executing it in C# like this:

```
var rowsAffected = 0;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Constants.Connection))
{
     conn.Open();

     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DeleteFromSchoolMain", conn);
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TblName", abundleBoard.TempName);
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MainID", abundleBoard.MainID.ToString());
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TblCol", abundleBoard.TblCol);

     SqlParameter outputParam = new SqlParameter();
     outputParam.ParameterName = "@rowsCount";
     outputParam.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
     outputParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
     cmd.Parameters.Add(outputParam);

     object o = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

     if (!outputParam.Value.Equals(DBNull.Value))
     {
         rowsAffected = Convert.ToInt32(outputParam.Value);
         string q = o.ToString();
     }

     conn.Close();
}
```

But my problem is I'm not getting anything in output parameter. I don't understand the problem, also I feels like my stored procedure is not optimised. Is there anything I can do to make the queries execute faster? Indexing and partitioning I've done my level best already.

**EDIT:**

So with help of @SurjitSD and @PeterB I got a resolution:-

In my Procedure I added the line at Top :-

```
SET @rowsCount=0
```

And in c# I've changed the code like :-

```
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 if (!cmd.Parameters["@rowsCount"].Value.Equals(DBNull.Value))
  {
   rowsAffected = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@rowsCount"].Value);
  }
```

For Now this works fine!

Comment: "_I'm not getting anything in output parameter_"  means what ? It is 0 ?

Comment: Yes it is 0. But my procedure should return number of rows affected it. No?

Comment: Try if starting the proc with `SET @rowsCount=0` helps

Comment: @PeterB You are a Man!! That Simple Thing was like an axe in my head. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @PeterB If only you can give some more time to see the optimisation part. My queries are taking a lot of time.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: just for my curiosity, why you declared  `o` as an object while your output parameter is an int ? would it be better if we declared it with `var` then convert the output to int?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `ExecuteScalar` in c#.

`ExecuteScalar` will give you firstRow and FirstColumn value returned by `Select` statement in procedure.

You need to use `ExecuteNonQuery`

After `ExecuteNonQuery`, you can get value like

```
cmd.Parameters["@rowsCount"].Value
```

> You can also get value using `ExecuteScalar` if you use `Select @rowsCount` after `set @rowsCount`.  Then you dont need to mention `output direction` to any parameter, both in sql and c#

Example with ExecuteScalar

**Sql procedure**

```
Alter procedure SomeProcedure
(
@someVariable int
:
:
)
Begin
   /*Some processing logic of procedure*/

    Select @SomeVariable //any variable Or Value from procedure needed as output in c#
End
```

**C#**

```
var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

——-**Edit**——

The actual reason for not getting value in c# was (with explanation)

The parameter `@rowsCount` was not initialized before using. So it was
`null` and when doing SET `@rowsCount = @TempCount + @rowsCount`, its actually adding something to `null`. And adding anything to `null` will be `null` as result.

So `@rowsCount` was always `null`.  Setting `@rowsCount=0` in begining of procedure helped.

Comment: I've used ExecuteNonQuery as well. It gives me 0.

Comment: Edited and included how to get value. @Deepak

Comment: But I haven't used TempRowCount in my SP or C#. Have I?

Comment: This is giving me Error @TempRowCount not declared. Using output parameter is good when you accept something in return. Right?

Comment: ExecuteScalar or ExecuteNonQuery, both works. They differ on the return value, but this return value has nothing to do with the @@rowcount and the value for the output parameter. Something is not as you think in the SP when executing the Dynamic SQL. I would try to test this SP in SSMS adding some PRINT to check what value is present in @@rowcount.

Comment: Its the name of output variable in your procedure that you want in output. I will edit answer to correct name @Deepak

Comment: @Steve . Do I need to change all the Dynamic queries? It'll be expensive for me! :(

Comment: Not sure, but here a search for you [@@rowcount dynamic sql](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%40%40rowcount%20dynamic%20sql&qs=HS&sk=HS0&pq=%40%40rowcount%20&sp=1&sc=8-11&form=BDKTKA&pc=BDT1&shash=&BDParam=0000&mkt=en-US)

Comment: @SurjitSD I've already tried the output parameter @@rowsCount. But still it gave me the Error for dbnull value.

Comment: @Deepak dont use double @. Mention exact name of your output variable. Edited answer too.

Comment: @SurjitSD Regarding that sentence saying that you don't need to specify output direction both in SQL and C#... At least for the SQL part I thought it was mandatory for an output parameter to specify OUTPUT in the SP declaration. Can you point me to documentation saying otherwise? Thanks!

Comment: When writing with @ StackOverflow thinks we are mentioning a name. That's why have to put 2 @s. Thanks for edit but still it doesn't work.

Comment: @JorgeY.  No «need to mention output direction» was only suggestion in case of execute scalar AND using «Select OutputParamName» in stored procedure as last statement. I have been using like this for long time now.  I will see some example for you.

Comment: @SurjitSD Ok, I get what you say now. No need for example. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Deepak  thats very strange. Kindly edit your question and tell what happens when you use executeScalar in c# and Select in StoredProcedure AND when you use ExecuteNonQuery without Select in stored procedure. Right now your question is a mix. Dont edit original question, put new text after it.

Comment: @SurjitSD The problem is solved with Peter's help. Thanks a lot to you too. Right now I'm concerned about the execution time. Will definitely Edit the question.

Comment: Wow. Nice. Having a quick look at your procedure nested subqueries tell me the resson of slowness. Nesting subqueries at multiple levels not very optimal to use.

Comment: Do I have any other option? My Subqueries are giving me the perfect result. But using joins or other options don't.

Comment: @Deepak i can see what i can suggest you more on performance, you can also try DBA stackexchange. https://dba.stackexchange.com